# How to reorganize dataframe with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble with Python to accomplish a task that is easily to be done on Excel.

There is a table (dataframe, or data set whatever) which consists of measurements I got from a device in my lab, I wanted it to be rearranged into a new table which should look like the one on the right side, so that I can have a better overview of my data. Let´s assume that a0 and a1, b0 and b1, c0 and c1 ... are comparable.

With my codes, I could get df_experiment(42 rows * 2 columns), concentration_start (21*2) and concentration_end (21*2). However, the objective dataframe I wanted, "df_combined", has 42 rows and 4 columns. So why is this happening? Why shouldn´t it be 21*4?

Other solutions without using pandas would also be helpful. Many thanks!

```
  col0  col1

0  a0    xxx                  a0   xxx   a1   xxx
1  b0    xxx                  b0   xxx   b1   xxx
2  c0    xxx                  c0   xxx   c1   xxx
   ...   ...    --------->    ...  ...   ...  ...
   ...   ...    --------->    ...  ...   ...  ...
21  a1    xxx    ---------> 
22  a2    xxx
23  a3    xxx
    ...   ...
41  ...   ...



import pandas as pd

# importing the data
df_experiment = pd.read_csv('component_concentration.txt', delimiter='\t', usecols=[0,1])

# dividing the whole table into two separate dataframes
concentration_start = df_experiment.iloc[0:21, :]
concentration_end = df_experiment.iloc[21:42, :]

# combining the two dataframes
df_combined = pd.concat([concentration_start, concentration_end], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I think you need to reset the index while concating , since pandas is index aligned : `df_combined = pd.concat([concentration_start.reset_index(drop=True), concentration_end.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: But btw, what does "ignore_index=True/False" define?

Comment: When you concat 2 dataframes vertically for example , like docs say: `do not use the index values along the concatenation axis. The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …, n - 1.` , and note this point too: `Note the index values on the other axes are still respected in the join.`